# Exporting glm prediction as raster?

Tags: raster, r, export

I have conducted a logistic regression in R using two rasters. I want to export it as a raster layer but I keep getting errors. the code is as follows:

```
S <- stack(sinks, tpi, beer)`
rdata <- data.frame(na.omit(values(s)))
model <- glm(sinks[]~tpi[]+beer[], data=rdata, family=binomial)
p = predict(model, newdata=data.frame(tpi=tpi[],beer=beer[]))
rf <- writeRaster(p, filename="test.tif", format="GTiff")

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeRaster’ for signature
‘"numeric", "character"’
```

Can anybody solve this problem?

Comment: Please make a reproducible example, perhaps with random data. I've answered some of your questions before and I don't want to go through setting up rasters again, so I'll give a quick answer in comments but not a full one unless you can make it easy for us!

Comment: `p` is not a raster - its a vector of values. You need to put those values back into a raster before you can write it but that might be complicated by your omission of NA values. Also your stack is `S` but your `rdata` comes from `s` and you are modelling with `sinks[]` which might not be the data in `rdata` so I have no idea what you are doing and this is confusing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, make some sample data. *You* should be doing this so all we have to do is cut and paste to see what your problem is:

```
library(raster)
tpi = raster(matrix(runif(50),5,10))
beer = raster(matrix(runif(50),5,10))
sinks = raster(matrix(runif(50)>.5,5,10))
```

I'll set some values to `NA` because I suspect you have some:

```
tpi[2,3]=NA
beer[1,1]=NA
```

Then you do this:

```
S <- stack(sinks, tpi, beer)
names(S)
# [1] "layer.1" "layer.2" "layer.3"
```

Note that the layer names are not the names of the individual rasters.

Then you so (with `S` replacing `s`):

```
 rdata <- data.frame(na.omit(values(S)))
```

Always check what you get, in this case:

```
 head(rdata)
 #  layer.1   layer.2    layer.3
 # 1       0 0.2671858 0.80993009
 # 2       1 0.5794600 0.95555964
 # 3       1 0.9979137 0.31638943
 dim(rdata)
 # [1] 48  3
```

a data frame with those layer names, and 48 rows because we've dropped the two `NA`s thanks to `na.omit`.

You then try and model with:

```
model <- glm(sinks[]~tpi[]+beer[], data=rdata, family=binomial)
```

which is going to take the values from the rasters you started with, not the `rdata` data frame you constructed. What you really want at this point is probably:

```
model <- glm(layer.1~layer.2+layer.3, data=rdata, family=binomial)
```

referring to the column names in `rdata` for fitting.

Then you try predictions:

```
p = predict(model, newdata=data.frame(tpi=tpi[],beer=beer[]))
```

which should fail because your model is in terms of `layer.2` and `layer.3` as covariates. So make a data frame with those names:

```
p = predict(model, newdata=data.frame(layer.2=tpi[],layer.3=beer[]))
```

Check for surprises:

```
summary(p)
#     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.     NA's 
# -0.69110  0.06903  0.43210  0.45960  0.81990  1.50900        2
```

That's a vector of length 50 with 2 NAs in it. Its not a raster.

However it has the values ready to put into a raster. We first make an empty raster of the same shape as one of your input rasters, and then put the values in:

```
praster = raster(beer)
praster[] = p
```

now you can:

```
writeRaster(praster, "praster.tif")
```

## Appendix

For readability you *can* rename the stack layers and that follows through into the data frame:

```
> names(S)=c("sinks","tpi","beer")
> data.frame(na.omit(values(S)))
   sinks        tpi       beer
1      0 0.26718584 0.80993009
2      1 0.57945999 0.95555964
3      1 0.99791372 0.31638943
4      0 0.73093333 0.95536213
```

but you *have* to understand when you are getting values from the data frame and when R is getting values from the raster objects with those names.